# Module `DatePickerIOS` does not exist in the Haste module map

Tags: android, react-native

While running ReactNative Android app getting the below Exception and also while Bundle, getting the same exception.

react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/

**Unable to resolve module `DatePickerIOS` from `Project_Path/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native-implementation.js`: Module `DatePickerIOS` does not exist in the Haste module map**

Kindly help me to resolve this.[image]

**Package.json:**
"dependencies": {
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.55.2",
    "react-native-calendars": "1.17.7",
    "react-native-carousel-view": "0.5.1",
    "react-native-confirmation-code-input": "1.0.4",
    "react-native-dash": "0.0.8",
    "react-native-elements": "0.19.1",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "0.7.0",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "1.3.6",
    "react-native-google-sign-in": "1.0.16",
    "react-native-i18n": "2.0.12",
    "react-native-indicators": "0.12.0",
    "react-native-maps": "0.21.0",
    "react-native-material-bottom-navigation": "0.9.0",
    "react-native-material-dropdown": "0.11.1",
    "react-native-material-ui": "1.22.1",
    "react-native-modalbox": "1.4.2",
    "react-native-searchbar": "1.14.0",
    "react-native-sensitive-info": "5.1.0",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "3.0.6",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "4.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "1.5.11",
    "react-native-tab-view": "0.0.77",
    "react-native-global-props": "1.1.3"
  }

Comment: Checkout this [link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14209#issuecomment-308428356)

Comment: Atlast it got worked by      npm start -- --reset-cache

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Terminate the process in the Metro bundler terminal window, and then as pointed out in the comments run `npm start -- --reset-cache`

Answer (score 1):

What happened with me for this problem,

I encountered this problem twice,

first time i mistakenly imported a js package when it was not installed, it resolved by removing that mistaken import statement

second time i was trying to install 'react-native-modal-overlay' package, and instead of using npm install, i used yarn add react-native-modal-overlay,
 and I started getting this problem

tried all steps i could find on net, but not resolved, finally, I took a fresh install of repository in another package, -----then also the build failed, t

-- then i ran npm cache clean, ( the result asked to run command 'npm install --cache /tmp/empty-cache'
-- i ran this command, and then tried to make build it succeeded